# Design of the web page on min-window

Tags: html, css

I am doing the mini-project by using only HTML and CSS, the problem is when I will be in max-size of the window the webpage design will be proper, but when I will minimize the window screen the huge white space will appear on the right side. Even I am using width=100vh and height=100vw.

Comment: Fellow user ! Did you tried anything :) It will require media query :) And a layout that fits our needs :)

Comment: It would be good if you add, example of your work with your question to check.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 100vw really **everywhere**? One larger element can cause it:

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 150vw; background-color: yellow; height: 50px;"></div>
  <p style="background-color: blue;">This element has the normal window width. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
```

Or it can cause padding if you havent setted `box-sizing: border-box;`

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 100vw; background-color: yellow; height: 50px; padding-right: 150px"></div>
  <p style="background-color: blue;">This element has the normal window width. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
```

Otherwise we need to know more details as said Nour-Allah Hussein, ideally code snippet.